# CSS dynamic grid positioning various heights

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a simple image grid in CSS that shows images in 4 columns with no gaps under them and dynamic floating positions.

CSS:

```
.img-grid .img-grid-item-holder {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.img-grid img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="img-grid">
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/800/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/350/750/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/600/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/410/430/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/320/650/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/350/750/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/600/cats" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41efz7ye/22/) showing the HTML and CSS I currently have. You can see there are spaces between the bottom right images.

[image]

I need it to look like this (or similar), and to allow the elements to sit neatly close to each other when I append new elements to img-grid div, while making sure the old elements keep their positions.

[image]

I tried to do this using CSS3 columns, but they don't play well with dynamically appending elements to the img-grid div making the old images change positions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a type of Masonry layout.
I just made it with http://masonry.desandro.com/

Check out the solution here

https://jsfiddle.net/41efz7ye/22/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.img-grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.img-grid-item-holder',
  columnWidth: 150
});
});
```

```css
.img-grid .img-grid-item-holder {
 width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.img-grid img {
 width: 100% !important;
 height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</script>
<div class="img-grid">
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/800/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/350/750/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/600/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/410/430/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/320/650/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/350/750/cats" />
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid-item-holder">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/600/cats" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does look rather impressive. Didn't know about Masonry, but this definitely does what I wanted. Thanks!